# Zooming a hotspot when it clicked

Tags: iphone, uiimage, zooming

I have to make some hot spots on my image , so that when i click anyone of them they zoom.

For example consider the image 
[image]

When i click that butterfly then it zoom

Please provide a good solution

Following are my thinking

- Use a button and click it and add a subImageView and zoom it.
- Zoom a particular region of this image when touch at that place.

Both ideas have their limitations.In first i have to create a saperate image and also my app size will become very large.
and limitation of second is that it will not zoom exact required image.

I was also thinking of masking but i think that is also not very good way, because this is just a sample, i have many images like this and can be many hot spots on a single image.

please guide.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing we rather large images you should check out CATiledLayer, which are very fast and efficient to use.

Check out this blog post, including the demo app:
http://www.cimgf.com/2011/03/01/subduing-catiledlayer/